# PHP I thought I had defined username, why is my code telling me otherwise?

Tags: php, html

I am struggling to understand why my code is telling me that my username is undefined whenever I try to load up this page. the error is Notice: Undefined index: username in /home/jmask072/public_html/login.php on line 12. Any help is appreciated.

```
<?php
    $users = array("user" => '$2y$10$yHL4GKr4pKxnBJ1L2xlqYuI/k0kviae2NbIQNJLFeXgVclT2hZeDi');
        $isLoggedIn = false;
        $errors = array();
        $required = array("username", "pass");
        foreach ($required as $key => $value) {
            if (!isset($_POST[$value]) || empty($_POST[$value])) {
                $errors[] = "please fill out the form";
            }
        }
        
        if (array_key_exists($_POST['username'],$users)) {
            $userPassword = $_POST['pass'];
            $dbPass = $users[$_POST['username']];
            if (password_verify($userPassword,$dbPass) === true) {
                $isLoggedIn = true;
            } else {
                $isLoggedIn = false;
                $errors[] = "Username not found or password incorrect";
            }
                
        } else {
            $errors[] = "Username not found or password incorrect";
        }

require_once("Template.php");

$page = new Template("My Login");
$page->addHeadElement("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"styles.css\">");
$page->addHeadElement("<script src='hello.js'></script>");
$page->finalizeTopSection();
$page->finalizeBottomSection();

print $page->getTopSection();

if (count($errors) > 0) {
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        print "Error";
    }
}
else if ($isLoggedIn === true) {
    print "Hello, you are logged in";
}

    
    
print "<form action =\"login_action.php\" method =\"POST\" class=\"form-signin\">";
print "<h1>Please sign in</h1>\n";
print "<label for=\"inputUser\">Username</label>";
print "<input type=\"password\" name=\"pass\" id=\"inputPassword\" placeholder=\"password\">";
print "<button type=\"submit\"> Sign in</button>";

print $page->getBottomSection();
?>
```

Comment: Typo: `method =\"POST"` should be `method =\"POST\"` you're missing the second backslash.

Comment: Why don't you just use single quotes so you don't need all those backslashes? I never understand why people make things harder for themselves like this.

Answer (score 1):

first you should use a single quotes **' '**
it is a very good alternative for backslash

and

```
 print "<label for='inputUser'>Username</label>";
```

here  you add label for `inputUser` but i dont see any input ??

Comment: also, `inputUser` is not `username`

Answer (score -1):

You do need to make the script "work" (meaning it should execute without errors; refusing to perform the operation and respond with a 4xx code counts as "working") even if the page is not requested correctly because you have no control on the requests it will get. Then you have to make sure that YOU call it correctly when you do it (right now this is not the case).

You are seeing the notice because, even if your code does check for the existence of the `POST` variables it needs (lines 6-10), it attempts to read them at line 12, even if the check failed.
The whole code block `if...then...else` starting at line 12 should only be executed if the checks went well (i.e. `if(empty($errors)) {...`). Now if the page is requested incorrectly at least you will get a useful error message that will help you understand where the problem with the request is.

In this case the error message is "*please fill out the form*". In fact the code expects a form with two input fields but the one it displays only has the password field (which is unhelpfully labelled "*Username*") and has no username field. You need to provide both fields and make sure that the name attributes match the `POST` variables you want to get the data from (the `for` attribute in the `label` tags should also match the field name exactly).